# i have an error of "Liquibase" error from Spring Boot Multi Module Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have problem of Spring boot multi module project.

i have 1 root project and 3 submodules.

```
root: api

 1. module-common
 2. module-client
 3. module-admin
```

this is my root's "build.gradle"

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.foodzim'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = '11'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.3'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.3'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

        // aws
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE'

        // excel
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2'
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2'

        // Database
        implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.3'

        //redis
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.4.5'

        // test
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.5.3'
        testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    }

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }

    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }
}

project(":module-client") {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":module-common")
    }
}

project(":module-admin") {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":module-common")
    }
}
```

module-common's "build.gradle"

```
dependencies {

    // spring starter
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'

    // JWT
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.2'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.2'

    //queryDSL
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.1:jpa'
    annotationProcessor 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api'
    annotationProcessor 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api'

    implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.12.1'

    // xml parser
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.12.4'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.4'


    testImplementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.12.1'
    testImplementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.4'


    // test queryDSL
    testImplementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt'
}
```

module-client's "build.gradle"

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
}
```

module-admin's "build.gradle"

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.3'
}
```

so i split the project into 3 sub modules and configure the build.gradles.

but when i run the project, this error message showed up.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
    at Application.main(Application.java:17) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:102) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:81) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Is there any solution to solve this problem??

Comment: try adding org.liquibase:liquibase-core as an implementation dependency of module-admin

Comment: still same problem.

Comment: What is the project that produced the error logs? Did you add any Liquibase related settings to your `application.yml/properties` without including Liquibase dependencies?

Comment: If you added new dependencies, make sure to update the `build.gradle`s.  Add your `application.yml` configs as well.

Comment: i solved it. that was buidl.gradle problem. i mismatch dependencies. thanks